# How to foreground a process started by upstart?

Tags: linux, bash, upstart

Is it possible to foreground a process started by upstart?

```
root@me:~# ps aux | grep my-app
root      2208  0.2  0.0   1456   480 ?        S    17:38   0:01 /opt/me/my-app
root@me:~# fg 2208
-bash: fg: 2208: no such job
root@me:~# fg $(pidof my-app)
-bash: fg: 2208: no such job
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fg` needs a job number, not a PID. There's no job number you can use because any process started by `upstart` is not a child of your shell. It won't appear in `jobs` output.

**Try `reptyr`**, e.g.:

```
reptyr 2208
```

From [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr):

> `reptyr` is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal.

Don't miss this note:

> `reptyr` depends on the `ptrace(2)` system call to attach to the remote program. On Ubuntu Maverick and higher, this ability is disabled by default for security reasons. You can enable it temporarily by doing
>
> ```
> echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
> ```
>
> as root, or permanently by editing the file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`, which also contains more information about this setting.

(Read more in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690).)

Also note `reptyr` only attaches a process to another terminal. This does not mean the process becomes a child of your current shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not seem to work for ffmpeg. Not sure why though. I get the error "Unable to open the tty in the child." For both the primary and child PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

The `fg`command needs the job_id not the process id, you need to run the `jobs` command and get the job_id of the process