# Bring a process to foreground suspended in another putty session

Tags: linux, putty, process

I'm just wondering whether I'll be able to bring a process to foreground which is started in one putty session into another putty session?

The issue I'm having right now is,
I started a python script (long running foreground process) in a putty session and due to some issues in network, the putty session got inactive. 
Then, I started a new putty session and checked whether the process is running or not with,

```
ps aux | grep python
```

The result of above command was,

```
tuser   35805 54.7  5.6 1632620 919720 pts/0  Sl   09:43  51:20 python train.py
```

Now, I would like to know whether I'll be able to bring this process in the currently logged in session? I would like to see the current status of the python script basically? Is there a way??

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to foreground a process started by upstart?](https://superuser.com/questions/1231023/how-to-foreground-a-process-started-by-upstart) My answer about `reptyr` applies.

Answer (score 3):

Without any workaround this can't be done, however: If you start your process inside a `screen` (or `tmux`) session, you can later reattach to the session from "another PuTTY" by doing `screen -dr`